# Allow special characters in Web API parameters

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, special-characters, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I need to be able to handle special characters in a `REST` call. Specifically the `.` and `/` characters.

For example I have a `GET` route `/api/division/{someDivision}`. Now, calling this route with a parameter of `/api/division/West Canada/` I get a return and everything works as expected. However, I need to be able to support other business divisions which have names such as "Southwest U.S." and "North/South America". Passing these parameters through my route returns a `404` via the api, since I presume, that the http handler thinks that the `.` and `/` characters make it think I'm referring to another domain or directory. Is there anyway to work around this so I can pass the needed parameter?

The route:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{division}/information")]
public IHttpActionResult DivisionInfo(string division)
{ 
  ...omitted for brevity
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting your route up like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/information")]
public IHttpActionResult DivisionInfo(string division)
```

Then you can call `GET http://website.com/api/information?division=text.with/special./characters`.

Comment: Is there no way to do it and keep the call RESTful?

Comment: There's nothing non-RESTful about having a query parameter for your search string. 

This article gives an example of a route doing just that: http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#advanced-queries

Answer (score 0):

try adding `[FromUri]` before the param:

```
Route("api/Person/{ID}/[FromUri]{UserName}")]
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit about this or provide link with some info about this

Answer (score 0):

Using an arbitrary string as the last URL Path does not work, because ASP.NET Web API interprets a `.` in the last URL Parameter as a File-Extension, which usually results in a `404 Not found`.

Even including an expected `.` in the Route does not work either e.g. with File Names `/api/division/{name}.{extension}`, because default Routing takes precedence.

Appending a unique fixed Literal helps (unless someDivision contains a Slash!):

`/api/division/{someDivision}/data`

The Morale is: don't use arbitrary strings in the Path.
Check the Documentation [ASP.NET Web API Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints)